# Phoenix Framework {:error, :econnrefused}

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to run some tests on my Phoenix app with the following line borrowed from [Phoenix](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/test/phoenix/integration/websocket_test.exs):

```
WebsocketClient.start_link(self, "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/socket/websocket")
```

(my websocket is set to just "/socket" in my Endpoint module; the above URL is exactly what my browser would connect to)

... which fails with `{:error, :econnrefused}`.

This error was mentioned in [a blog post](http://dantswain.herokuapp.com/blog/2015/04/19/integration-testing-a-json-api-in-phoenix/) which suggested putting a variant of the following snippet:

```
defmodule Calculon.Support.Helpers do
  def launch_api do
    # set up config for serving
    endpoint_config =
      Application.get_env(:calculon, Calculon.Endpoint)
      |> Keyword.put(:server, true)
    :ok = Application.put_env(:calculon, Calculon.Endpoint, endpoint_config)

    # restart our application with serving enabled
    :ok = Application.stop(:calculon)
    :ok = Application.start(:calculon)
  end
end
```

... in a setup_all:

```
setup_all do
  Calculon.Support.Helpers.launch_api
end
```

But to no avail. I've also tried this snippet used within Phoenix's websocket test (linked above):

```
Application.put_env(:phoenix, Endpoint, [
  https: false,
  secret_key_base: String.duplicate("abcdefgh", 8),
  debug_errors: false,
  pubsub: [adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2, name: __MODULE__],
  http: [port: @port],
  server: true
])
```

None of these have worked for me so far yet though. Is there anything obvious I may have missed?

Comment: Is the 8080 port open on your firewall?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci: using `phoenix.server` and running everything from browser on that port seems fine... so I'd believe so.